# Webservice public class of Webservice isn't available

Tags: c#, web-services, class

I have a problem in my Windows Store Application.

I Have a Webservice hosted remotely on a server :

```
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public class CustoSpec {
        public string VisitIDSpec { get; set; }

    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Prenom { get; set; }
        public string Born { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int MVue { get; set; }
        public int Mvloin { get; set; }
        public int MvPres { get; set; }
        public int MvLoinPres { get; set; }
        public int MvvAbime { get; set; }
        public string MVAutre { get; set; }
        public int NOrdo { get; set; }
        public int NMonture { get; set; }
        public int Clunette { get; set; }
        public string RAutre { get; set; }
        public int PSolaire{ get; set; }
        public int PSolaireSol { get; set; }
        public int PSolaireAdapt { get; set; }
        public int PLunette { get; set; }
        public int PLentille { get; set; }
        public string  VOphta { get; set; }
        public string VOpticien { get; set; }
        public int Discrete { get; set; }
        public int Petite { get; set; }
        public int Actuelle { get; set; }
        public int Resistante { get; set; }
        public int Metal { get; set; }
        public int Plastique { get; set; }
        public int Fine { get; set; }
        public int Legere { get; set; }
        public int Grande { get; set; }
        public int Caractere { get; set; }
        public int Epaisse { get; set; }
        public string Marque { get; set; }
        public string Forme { get; set; }
        public string Couleurs { get; set; }
        public int NbLunette { get; set; }
        public int Budget { get; set; }
        public string Delai { get; set; }
        public string IDocumentation { get; set; }
        public string IOrdinateur { get; set; }
        public string IConsultation { get; set; }
        public string ICommerce { get; set; }
        public string IManuel { get; set; }
        public string IPrecision { get; set; }
        public string IMaison { get; set; }
        public string IEtude { get; set; }
        public string Autre { get; set; }
        public string IAutre { get; set; }
        public string Sport { get; set; }
        public string ISport { get; set; }
        public string ILecture { get; set; }
        public int LectureNbH { get; set; }
        public string LectPosAl { get; set; }
        public string InstrumentM { get; set; }
        public string IMusique { get; set; }
        public string IMultimedia { get; set; }
        public string IOrdinateurLoisir { get; set; }
        public string ITravailExt { get; set; }
        public string Creation { get; set; }
        public string ICreation { get; set; }
        public string AutreLoisir { get; set; }
        public string IAutreLoisir { get; set; }
        public string Conduite { get; set; }
        public string PMedical { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public string Synthese { get; set; }
        public int VisitID { get; set; }
        public int VisitIDToSpec {get; set;}
    }
```

after generating, publishing the webservice and updated the service reference in my application, the Customer class is available but not the CustoSpec in my application !

I tried to reboot the server, restart my host, but nothing change.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

The only classes which will be "available" on the client are those which are used in a request or response by the service.